# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipickerview

In my code, three text fields are there for picker views. For example in the first text field, the user selects A+ blood group, in the second text field we don't want to display A+ blood group. Remaining items need to display. Text field 3 also same. For example, in text field 2 the user selects B+ blood group, in text field 3 B+ and A+ blood group needs to remove in array list. For example the user again selects the first text field and reselects another blood group like A- ve group re add the A+ blood group in array list. The same thing in text field2 and text field3. I got some exception. The exception is

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]'

My json Response is:

```
question is :(
        
{
        
Question = "What is your first pet's name?";
        
QuestionID = 23;
    
},
        
{
        
Question = "Who was your first grade teacher?";
        
QuestionID = 24;
    
},
        
{
        
Question = "What city were you born in?";
        
QuestionID = 25;
    
},
        
{
        
Question = "What was your childhood nickname?";
        
QuestionID = 26;
    
},
        
{
        
Question = "What was the name of your elementary school?";
        
QuestionID = 27;
    
},
        
{
        
Question = "Where does your nearest relative live?";
        
QuestionID = 28;
    
},
        
{
        
Question = "In what city or town was your first job?";
        
QuestionID = 29;
    
},
        
{
        
Question = "Which is your first car?  Edited ";
        
QuestionID = 30;
    
},
        
{
        
Question = "This is a test question - answer = ddi";
 
QuestionID = 32;
    
},
        
{
        
Question = "What is your Mother's maiden name?";
        
QuestionID = 33;
    
},
        
{
        
Question = "What is your Last name?";
        
QuestionID = 35;
    
},
        
{
        
Question = "What is the last 4 of your SSN?";
        
QuestionID = 36;
    
},
        
{
        
Question = "What is your Date of Birth? (MM/DD/YYYY)";
        
QuestionID = 37;
    
}

)
```

---

```
-(void)done:(id)sender
```

{

int row = [myPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];

if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[dict setObject:QArray[row] forKey:@"title"];

NSInteger currentRow = row;

[dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",currentRow] forKey:@"selectedIndex"];

[backUpArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:dict];

selectedValue1 = QidArray[row];

bloodGroup.text = QArray[row];

[QArray removeObjectAtIndex:row];

[QidArray removeObjectAtIndex:row];

selectedItem1=bloodGroup.text;

NSLog(@"Selected row value 1 of Picker view is:%@",selectedItem1);

}

else if((!isBloodGroupFieldSelected) && (isGenderGroupFieldSelected))

{

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[dict setObject:QArray[row] forKey:@"title"];

NSInteger currentRow = row;

[dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",currentRow] forKey:@"selectedIndex"];

[backUpArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:dict];

txtField1.text = QArray[row];

selectedItem2 = txtField1.text;

selectedValue2 = QidArray[row];

[QArray removeObjectAtIndex:row];

[QidArray removeObjectAtIndex:row];

}

else if(!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)

{

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[dict setObject:QArray[row] forKey:@"title"];

NSInteger currentRow = row;

[dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",currentRow] forKey:@"selectedIndex"];

[backUpArray replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:dict];

txtField2.text= QArray[row];

selectedItem3= txtField2.text;

selectedValue3 = QidArray[row];

NSLog(@"Selected row value 3 of Picker view is.....:%@",selectedValue3);

NSLog(@"selected item value 1 of picker view is:%@",selectedItem3);

[QArray removeObjectAtIndex:row];

[QidArray removeObjectAtIndex:row];

}

[myPickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

[bloodGroup resignFirstResponder];

[txtField1 resignFirstResponder];

[txtField2 resignFirstResponder];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {

if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {

return 1;

}

else if(!isBloodGroupFieldSelected){

return 1;

}

else if(!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)

{

return 1;

}

return 0;

}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {

eturn [QArray count];

}

else if(!isBloodGroupFieldSelected)

{

return [QArray count];

}

else if(!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)

{

return [QArray count];

}

return 0;

}

## pragma mark - UIPickerViewDelegate

// #5
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {

return QArray[row];

}

else if((!isBloodGroupFieldSelected) && (isGenderGroupFieldSelected))

{

return QArray[row];

}

else if(!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)

{

return QArray[row];

}

return 0;

}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
  {

UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 50)];

lblTitle.numberOfLines=2;

lblTitle.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

lblTitle.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];

lblTitle.text=QArray[row];

return lblTitle;

}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

if (textField == bloodGroup) {

isBloodGroupFieldSelected = YES;

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[backUpArray objectAtIndex:0]];

NSString *str = [dict objectForKey:@"title"]?[dict objectForKey:@"title"]:@"";

NSInteger *index = (int)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"selectedIndex"]].intValue;

int count = (int) index;

if(str.length > 0){

[QArray insertObject:str atIndex:0];

}

}

else if (textField == txtField1){

isBloodGroupFieldSelected = NO;

isGenderGroupFieldSelected = YES;

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[backUpArray objectAtIndex:1]];

NSString *str = [dict objectForKey:@"title"]?[dict objectForKey:@"title"]:@"";

NSInteger *index = (int)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"selectedIndex"]].intValue;

int count = (int) index;

if(str.length > 0){

[QArray insertObject:str atIndex:0];

}

}

else if (textField == txtField2){

isGenderGroupFieldSelected = NO;

isBloodGroupFieldSelected = NO;

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[backUpArray objectAtIndex:2]];

NSString *str = [dict objectForKey:@"title"]?[dict objectForKey:@"title"]:@"";

NSInteger *index = (int)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"selectedIndex"]].intValue;

int count = (int) index;

if(str.length > 0){

[QArray insertObject:str atIndex:0];

}

}

[myPickerView reloadAllComponents];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
  {

[super viewDidLoad];

backUpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){

dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[backUpArray insertObject:dict atIndex:i];

}

}

Comment: The real causer of the error is not in this code.

Comment: @vadian i put the exception break point and run the application. i got the exception in this line of code.  selectedValue1 = QidArray[row];

Comment: It's obvious that the error occurs in this line but the reason is somewhere else. The error message says that `row` is 10 (which points to the 11th item) but the array contains only 10 items. So the error is related to the data source of the picker.

Comment: @vadian can you create a chat room please. i post my total code. so you can look at. please help me

Comment: Please edit the question and add the relevant code so others could help, too.

Comment: @vadian i paste my entire code. can you please look my code?

Comment: @vadian can you check my code and please give me the solution. i paste my code

Comment: Could you add some sort of formatting to your code. It will be easier to read than just a wall of text. Thanks.